# Can mobile apps be rejected for using access origin = *

Tags: cordova

I am using phonegap/cordova to build a mobile application for apple/android/blackberry which searches for travel agents in the USA. If the app displays search results, an option is to see the travel agent's website.
  In order for me to do that, my understanding of using phonegap/cordova is that any website that i need to access through my application needs to be added to the whitelist (the case for apple). My question is the following: If in my config.xml file i simply use

```
<access subdomains="true" origin="*"/>
```

Do I risk having my application rejected from Apple's App store? or Google Play?

Answer (score 2):

there is no specific line in apple guide line about any limitation to wich url's you could open in your application and as seen in phonegap document about white list it informs you that you can use *  so it should not be a problem at all:

> Access to all the subdomains on google.com (e.g. mail.google.com and docs.google.com):
>
> *.google.com

but i strongly suggest you to limit access because no one know what apple do about it.